# Are mushrooms growing naturally in your garden a sign of good soil health?

Tags: soil, mushrooms

I noticed that in my "wild" community garden plot I have small mushrooms growing in my garden, but I don't know what type they are. Is this a sign of good soil health?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not particularly - mushrooms or toadstools are usually saphrophitic, meaning they're feeding off dead plant material, often of woody origin. This might mean your soil is high in humus of woody origin, or it might just mean you've got, or have used,  bark chips, or there's a tree stump or something somewhere.

Comment: I did use coffee grounds on the surface to try to feed plants this summer by sprinkling them all over the plot.